# RewriteRule in .htaccess for www and https on generic domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

THESE TWO BOTH WORK:

`http://example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com`

`http://www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com`

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

`https://example.com` redirect to `https://www.example.com`

When I try that last one, the browser just spins and spins, never loads anything. Like its in an infinite redirect loop. How can I make all three of these cases redirect to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: Yes, I have tested in more than one browser, and get the same result.

Comment: I just tested your code on my server and it works fine. The problem you are having could be due to your browser cache or other clinet-side or server-side redirects.

Comment: You are correct, that was the problem, thanks!